# TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.firestore is not a function firebase y react error

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, firebase, npm

Estoy tratando de integrar firebase con react pero siempre obtengo este error
`TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.firestore is not a function` tengo un archivo `firebase.js` con el siguiente código

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "My key",
   authDomain: "My domain",
   projectId: "crud-258a3",
   storageBucket: "crud-258a3.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "ID",
   appId: "ID"
}

export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Luego cuento con un archivo `actions.js` con el siguiente codigo:

```
import {firebaseApp} from './firebase'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const db = firebase.firestore(firebaseApp)

export const getCollection = async(collection) => {
    const resultado = {statusResponse: false, data:null, error: null}

    try {

        const data = await db.collection(collection).get()
        console.log(data);
    
    } catch (error) {
        resultado.error = error
    }

    return resultado
}
```

Y mi archivo `app.js` con lo siguiente, priemro trate de guardar en memoria los datos a manera de ejemplo ya hora tratao de integrar con firebase, mi codigo es:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {isEmpty,size} from 'lodash'
import shortid from 'shortid'
import { getCollection } from './actions'

function App() {

  const [task, setTask] = useState("")
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false)
  const [idMode, setIdMode] = useState("")
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async ()=>{
      const result = await getCollection("task")
    })()
  }, [])
```

Teóricamente con esto tendría que traer todos los datos de mi base de datos pero me genera el error comentado anterior mente, y no que hacer, ya he creado dos veces el proyecto pero aun asi sigue presentado el mismo error, que estoy haciendo mal?? que me puede estar afectando??

Comment: y qué pasa si usas `firebaseApp.firestore()`?

Comment: Lo mismo, el mismo problema

Comment: En ese caso puede que webpack no incluya a firestore en el bundle por el uso de protobuffers. Prueba incluyendo firebase desde el cdn con un script tag en el html. Es feo pero práctico

Comment: Si de esa manera si funciona, pero lo idela seria hacerlo mediante la instalacion de los paquetes

Comment: qué versión estás usando? Hay más de un issue en los repos de Firebase SDK, pero datan de la versión 6 y 7. En particular, [el uso de gRPC como causa raíz aparece en el bundle para serverless](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2010#issuecomment-516646790) pero no le encuentro sentido a la explicación. Lamentablemente no uso firestore, sólo messaging y cloud storage